# What do you call a person who installs window panes?

Tags: nouns

When building a house, the person who puts up the framing is the ***builder***, the person who wires the electrics is the ***electrician***, the person who does the plumbing is the ***plumber***.

Who fixes and installs windows?

The glass man?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No I don't. As far as I remember you posted window fitter originally. I'll have a look at the edit history tomorrow.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - As far as I can see - you added glazier to your answer 4 hours ago, while hotlicks answered 'glazier' 'yesterday' whatever that is.

Comment: You should clarifyyour question: "window panes" are replaced by a "glazier" when they get broken, but when you build a house you do **not** call a glazier, you buy windows and a carpenter ("window installer") installs them. Do you get it? The text of your question conflicts with its title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person is a [glazier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glazier):  one who sets glass

Comment: How is this an improvement on the answer already given by @Mari-Lou A? What about a person who installs windows, as mentioned by OP?

Answer (score 6):

A *glazier*, sometimes spelled as *glazer*, is also known as a **[glass worker](http://newfoundland.craigslist.ca/trd/5257876109.html)**. The Free Dictionary mentions that a [**glassworker**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glassworker)  (one word), is a person who *cuts* flat glass to size.

Common synonyms include: ***glass cutter***, ***glass-cutter***; ***glass installer***, and ***glass setter***

Not to be confused with:  *[glassblower](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glassblower)*, *[glassmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassblowing)*, or *[glassmaker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glassmaker)*, who are workers/ tradesmen/people who *make* glass.

One final synonym comes from the American website, Craigslist, which defines the job position of a **Glass Technician** as

> Our client, […], is looking for a dependability enthusiastic candidate for an apprentice Flat Glass (Glazier) Technician for their growing team in St. John's, Newfoundland.
>
> Responsibilities
>
> • Repair/ replace commercial and residential glass and glazing systems
> • Measure, fabricate and install mirrors, glass and custom showers
> • Perform mobile service glazing

Answer (score 3):

Consider **window installer**:

> *Should I Become a Window Installer?*
> *Window installers fit pre-made windows into window openings and door frames of homes and buildings.*

([study.com](http://study.com/articles/Become_a_Window_Installer_Step-by-Step_Career_Guide.html))

From [service reviews](http://www.yelp.com/biz/american-window-company-covina-2) of *American Window Company*:

> The **installer** Manny and his assistant were quick, neat and very professional. My windows look awesome and I can already tell a difference in sound and insulation
>
> The **installers** left the house as if they had never been there.

Comment: That could be ambiguous, it could also mean someone who installs Windows (MS) on your computer.

Comment: Well, context is king. Also, what you apparently mean is "Windows Installer". Note the trailing "s" and the capitalization. It's a Windows component, not a person: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe it's just me (I work in tech), but I wouldn't call a person a Windows installer, except perhaps humorously :)